# Prevent Bootstrap tooltip from showing when ancestor has given class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a sidebar menu that the user can collapse to icons when desired to minimize the horizontal space the menu takes. When the menu is collapsed and you hover a menu icon, its usual menu text extends out to the right. A few menu items also have Bootstrap tooltips attached to them, which show up to the right of the entry to show more information than would reasonably fit in the menu.

When the menu is collapsed, though, those tooltips get in the way of the menu text showing on the right. I want the tooltips to be on the full menu item (so hovering over both the icon and the text when it's expanded works), so I can't just assign the tooltip to the menu text.

When the menu is collapsed, it gets an additional class added to it to flag that.

Is there a *simple* way to suppress those tooltips only when the menu is collapsed, without having to reinitialize the tooltip stuff on each relevant element whenever the menu's collapsed state changes?

The stripped down version is, given this HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div title="A tooltip">Menu item 1</div>
    <div title="Another tooltip">Menu item 2</div>
    <div title="Another tooltip">Menu item 3</div>
</div>
```

And this code hooking up the tooltips:

```
$(".sidebar [title]").tooltip();
```

Is there a simple way to prevent those tooltips from being shown when `.sidebar` has `.min`? Without having to call `tooltip("destroy")` when adding `.min` and then call `tooltip()` again when removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is easier than I thought it was going to be: The `show.bs.tooltip` event *bubbles* and also can be cancelled, so if I catch it on `.sidebar`, I can check for whether `.sidebar` has `.min` and cancel the event:

```
$(".sidebar").on("show.bs.tooltip", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("min")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or if I have a variety of elements I want to do that on, I could catch it on `document` and then look for a marker class on a relevant ancestor of `e.target` (which is the element the tooltip is associated with):

```
$(document).on("show.bs.tooltip", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".min")[0]) { // or whatever class is relevant
        return false;
    }
});
```